# How to write the following if-then condition in Mixed Integer Programming? If a<b then c=1, 0 otherwise

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming

I am new to mixed-integer programming and I am confused about how to approach this if-then condition.
How do I the following constraint in mixed-integer programming:
if Dm +t < Dn +  then Zmn=1, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enforce a strict inequality, so you must choose between two formulations that come close but do not exactly match what you want. I'll phrase this in terms of the title of your question. In both versions, $c$ is a binary variable.

Option 1: $a \ge b - M_1 c$ and $a \le b + M_2(1-c)$, where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are suitably large constants. If $a > b$ this forces $c=0$, and if $a < b$ this forces $c=1$. The downside is that if $a=b$, $c$ can be either 0 or 1.

Option 2: $a \ge b - M_1 c$ and $a \le b - \epsilon + M_2(1-c)$, where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are suitably large constants and $\epsilon > 0$ is a small constant (but not so small as to look like rounding error to your solver). If $a \ge b$ this forces $c=0$, and if $a \le b-\epsilon$ this forces $c=1$. The downside is that $b-\epsilon < a < b$ is now infeasible.

Comment: Thank you very much prubin! This was very helpful indeed!

Comment: Does anything change if a<=b? 
Also, If i want c=0 if a=b, can i formulate it as a<=b+Mc and a>=b-M(c )?

Comment: For $a\le b \implies c=1$, option 1 stays the same and option 2 changes to $a\ge b -M_1 c + \epsilon$ and $a\le b + M_2(1-c)$. To answer your second question, no. The formulation you propose forces $a=b$ if $c=0$ but puts no restrictions on $a$ and $b$ if $c=1$. So you could have $a=b$ and $c=1$.